# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error reported on Sony devices in setContentView()

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error reported only on Sony devices e.g. - ( D6603 , SGP521 ) with Android 5.1.1.

The line of my code in the stack trace is a call to Activity.setContentView(). Thanks.

The stack trace :-

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blacklight.klondike.patience.solitaire/com.blacklight.klondike.patience.solitaire.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
    Caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
           at android.content.res.Resources.toPreloadCookie(Resources.java:2491)
           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2519)
           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:828)
           at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3640)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3687)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:372)
           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
           at com.blacklight.klondike.patience.ParentActivity.onCreate(ParentActivity.java:430)
           at com.blacklight.klondike.patience.solitaire.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

**ParentActivity** -

```
public class ParentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener/*,ButtonNeedsUpdateDelegate*/ {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.full_game_layout);

        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        initFacebook(savedInstanceState);


}
}
```

**R.layout.full_game_layout** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ads_size"
    android:visibility="invisible" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/daily_topbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Daily_top_bar_h"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/daily_shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/daily_home_caller"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <com.blacklight.klondike.patience.customviews.RobotoMTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="02"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:id="@+id/daily_home_date"
                android:textSize="@dimen/xlarge_text"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"

                />


            <com.blacklight.klondike.patience.customviews.RobotoMTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Feb"
                android:id="@+id/daily_home_month"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/home_divider_h"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black_transparent_1"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/daily_home_caller1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <com.blacklight.klondike.patience.customviews.RobotoMTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/popup_title_color"
                android:text="@string/daily_clng"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_med_text"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.blacklight.klondike.patience.customviews.RobotoMTextView
                    android:id="@+id/daily_home_timer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_color"
                    />

                <com.blacklight.klondike.patience.customviews.RobotoMTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/time_left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_med_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_color"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yesterday_leaderboard"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ldb_right_round_corner"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/radio_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/radio_size"
                android:src="@drawable/daily_leaderboard"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Daily_top_bar_h"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/radio_size"
            android:id="@+id/right_tick"
            android:src="@drawable/right_tick"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/play_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/daily_topbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pager_include"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home_setting"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/home_setting"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/home_achivements"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/home_achivements"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_screen_padding">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/symbol_img"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_dimen"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_dimen"
            android:src="@drawable/taptoplay_1"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.blacklight.klondike.patience.customviews.RobotoLTextView
                android:id="@+id/home_play"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/tap_to_play"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/med_large_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.blacklight.klondike.patience.customviews.RobotoLTextView
            android:id="@+id/game_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/plus_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/theme_icn_w"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pager_include"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/pager_include"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_pager_h"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dot_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        layout="@layout/home_stats_view"/>

    <!--layout="@layout/home_stats_view"-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dot_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/page_indicator1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dot_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dot_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/page_indicator2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dot_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dot_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dot_size"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dot_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/page_indicator3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dot_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dot_size" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_setting"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pager_include"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_1"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/self_managed_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/more_games"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/more_games"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home_setting"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/moregames_selector" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/daily_topbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.sessionm.api.PortalButton
            android:id="@+id/portalButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
            android:background="@drawable/sessionm"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" >
        </com.sessionm.api.PortalButton>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fb_invite_home"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
            android:src="@drawable/fb_invite_selector_1"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/removeads_icon_fulllayout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_above="@+id/home_setting"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/home_setting"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/noadd"
        android:visibility="gone" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inviteFriends"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_icn_dimen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/daily_topbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/fb_share_img"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/home_screen_padding"
        android:text="SHARE To Unlock"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/med_large_text"
        android:visibility="visible" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post you code please ?

Comment: @Jhaman Das , I edited my question with code (Activity and Layout)

Comment: @ajaychauhan, hi have you solved this issue?, because same issue I am getting

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit please try my answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Because  you are not posting the code

Check this :

The Error is

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6

#### Explanation :

> Java arrays start at 0, not 1. That means the first element of an
>   array is accessed using `array[0]`, the second with `array[1]`, etc.
>   As such, to access the last element of an array, use
>   `array[array.length - 1]`. Using `array[array.length]` is one index
>   out of bounds, hence the exception.

Comment: Your answer not related to my question ,  error seems to be in Layout file

Answer (score 0):

I saw this crash with one of my apps and it was related to `toPreloadCookie` being unable to parse certain resources (For me it was "?android:colorAccent").

What I would suggest is visiting each drawable in that layout, and for each xml drawable listed, see if any of them reference a non-project scope resource and replacing it.

ie: `?android:colorAccent` with `@color/colorAccent`

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

The crash was happening on my app because of using the DeviceDefault (e.g. Theme.DeviceDefault.Light) themes.

To fix it, I've changed all activities to use android  default themes like Material and Holo.